# Unit tests for Angular Post API calls

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, integration-testing

I am new for unit testing. My api makes post request. I want to know,what kind of unit tests can be done for Post request using HttpTestingController?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

Comment: It's like you are asking what is Angular, spend some time to understand it than asking every think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend testing things like:

- Does the API return same object that you send to API?
- Does the API return correct status code? (200 for OK, 201 for new creation)
- If you request objects (for example) ordered by value, test does it actually do it

Answer (score 2):

Check this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@Jestfer/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf) for more details. In this brief article, it shows you how to test your HTTP Requests in Angular, using the `HttpClientTestingModule` and the `HttpTestingController`, both from `@angular/common/http/testing` dependency.